# Error desconocido en Genexus 15

Tags: genexus

Buen día muchachos, el día de hoy vengo con un error que hasta el momento no sé a que se debe, ni sé como solucionarlo.
Trabajo con Genexus 15 Java y quiero hacer un for each a mi tabla para validar que un registro ya existe y al momento de darle RUN o Buil All, ocurre esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero intencionalmente le cambio la tabla al for each y el error no sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien podría ayudarme por favor, o capaz esta no es la forma de validar si un registro existe o no.

Disculpen la demora. Pero no se si lo dije, pero recien estoy manejando GeneXus y no sé aún algunos detalles.

Adjunto mis Navegaciones.

Error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Angel, Para poder ayudarte, el mejor és tener ambas navegaciones, pero es casi cierto que tienes algun atributo en la pantalla que esta haciendo esa webpanel tener tabla base, y, luego, un for each en la misma tabla genera un break.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo amigo, pero no entendí bien eso de tener ambas navegaciones, y sobre si tengo algún atributo en mi tabla, poes solo tengo una grilla con una tabla base, pero ya intenté quitarla y sigue ocurriendo el mismo error.
Espero puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angel,

Lo que dice es que para ayudarte, el mejor es que tengamos el navigation view de tu objeto.

Pero, ya diciste que hay una tabla base.

En esto caso, siempre que hay una tabla base, y un for each en la misma tabla, genexus genera un break, esto es por definicion.

Creo que lo que intentas es en una tela que lista registros tener un boton para agregar un nuevo registro, y solo agrega caso no exista.

En ese caso, creo que el mejor, para tu caso, sea hacer el for each en una sub.

Quedaria algo como:

```
Event 'agregar'
    ...
    If ...
        Do ' verifica email'
    Endif
EndEvent

Sub 'verifica email'

    For each
    ...
    Endfor

Endsub
```

Tengo como sugerencia que revise los temas de for each e determinacion de tabla base.

Tambien el tema de la nomenclatura gik, pues no es una buena pratica tener atributos como "descripcion".

Comment: Hola Sandro, disculpa la demora, acabo de adjuntar las navegaciones, Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Hola Sandro, probé ese ejemplo que me diste y funciona correctamente pero no sé por qué ocurre esto. Agrego un dato, y cuando agrego otro, sea duplicado o no, me sale "Error al acceder al servidor o algo así" pero cuando le quito el for each, ya no sale ese error. Debo decir que con el antiguo "For each" ocurria igual esto.
Saludos.
Nuevamente gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Me faltó indicar de que ese For each ya con Sub Rutine , lo estoy manejando en PopUp, pero de nuevo gracias, no sabia que los Sub se usaban de esta manera y créeme que me ha ayudado muchísimo.
Ahora mi ultima pregunta, cuando quiera hacer ese tipo de validaciones, siempre las debo hacer en un SUB?
Saludos.

Comment: Angel, es difícil, pues depende del contexto, pero en general, la respuesta es no.
Depende en la realidad de la tabla base de la webpanel, si lo quieres hacer un for each en la misma tabla base *sin* generar un break (quizas lo quieras), si, debe hacer este for each en una sub. 

También lo puedes hacer un procedure de validacion, y llamarlo en en evento de la webpanel. O que creo brindar una segregación mas clara, sin embargo lo puedes usar este mismo procedimiento en otras pantallas, o partes del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Y si dejas el for each sin nombre de transacción?

Gx lo infiere sólo

For each
   Where idempresa....
Aunque puede ser lo que dice Sandro.

Con respecto a lo que dice Sandro, es ver el Navigation view que tienes ahí abierto.

Y comparar las navegaciones en los 2 casos.

Comment: Si dejo "For each " solo, igual me dá el error :/